# Swift: handling an unexpected nil value, when variable is not optional

Tags: swift, null, option-type

I have a `UITableViewController` loading its entries from Core Data via a `NSFetchedResultsController`. Like this:

```
let historyItem = fetchedResults.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as HistoryItem
```

`historyItem` has a `title` property defined like this:

```
@NSManaged var title: String
```

So in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the code says

```
cell?.textLabel?.text = historyItem.title
```

and that should all be fine. `title` is not an optional and does not need unwrapping.

However, in the past, the stored Core Data has acquired some objects where the value of the `title` property is `nil`. They are there stored, waiting to cause errors. If one of these objects is displayed in a cell, I will see a runtime address exception on the above Swift code line, where the address is 0.

For robustness, I need to write code to make sure the stored data delivered to my program does not cause crashes. However, I cannot write

```
if historyItem.title == nil { } // gives compiler error
```

because `title` is not an optional and the compiler will not let me. If I write

```
let optionalTitle:String? = historyItem.title
```

I still get a runtime `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on that line.

**How can I check that `title` is not erroneously nil?**

Thanks!

Comment: I have closed as a duplicate because I think it is the same problem. Let me know if those solutions do not apply in your case, then I will reopen the question.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the same case (which I failed to find with my searches), but the high-marked solution there does not work. I will ask another question pointing that out. Thanks!

Comment: I asked another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031080/swift-detecting-an-unexpected-nil-value-in-a-non-optional-at-runtime-casting-a

Answer (score 0):

Since you have nil values, the `title` property should be optional and you should declare it as optional in your core data model and in your `NSManagedObject` historyItem class.

Comment: If I just change the type of title to String?, (and change all the places where title is used through the code, to unwrap it) then the core data code gives runtime errors. I could write a migrator, maybe... but I'd much rather just check for the unexpected nil value.

Answer (score 0):

When I do this in editor I dont get an error so might be the answer:

```
let a = ""

if a as String? == nil {
        println("Nil")
    }
    else {
        println("Not nil")
    }
```

Comment: Looks promising! Unfortunately, it doesn't work. If I write `if historyItem.title as String? == nil { t = "was Nil" }` then I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS if title is nil.

Comment: Try ```if let historyItemTitle = historyItem.title as? String { "historyItem.title not nil" } else { "historyItem.tile is nil" }```

Comment: Or if you make that title of type :String! this will enable nil comparison.

Answer (score 0):

`@NSManaged var title: String` should be `@NSManaged var title: String?` if there is possibility for a nil value. Then, you cannot go wrong with optional binding:

```
if let historyItemTitle = historyItem.title {
  cell?.textLabel?.text = historyItemTitle
} else {
  cell?.textLabel?.text = "Title missing"
}
```