# Swift: detecting an unexpected nil value in a non-optional at runtime: casting as optional fails

Tags: swift, core-data, null, option-type

I have a `UITableViewController` loading its entries from Core Data via a `NSFetchedResultsController`. Like this:

```
let historyItem = fetchedResults.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as HistoryItem
```

`historyItem` has a `title` property defined like this:

```
@NSManaged var title: String
```

but somehow the core data has a nil value for `title` in some entries which causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS because `title` is not `String?`. This problem has been addressed at [Check if property is set in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661120/check-if-property-is-set-in-core-data) and the high-voted answer there suggests something like this:

```
    if let possibleTitle = historyItem.title as String? {
        NSLog("possibleTitle was set OK")
    } else {
        NSLog("possibleTitle was nil")
    }
```

but I just tried that and it still gave me EXC_BAD_ACCESS:
[image: Xcode screen grab]

That same problem and solution is also mentioned at 
[Swift - casting a nil core data string as an optional value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411837/swift-casting-a-nil-core-data-string-as-an-optional-value) and my earlier duplicate question [Swift: handling an unexpected nil value, when variable is not optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029542/swift-handling-an-unexpected-nil-value-when-variable-is-not-optional)
but it doesn't work for me. I'm using Xcode 6.2 and iOS8.

Am I misunderstanding something, please? Should this approach work?

Comment: That is interesting. I can confirm that the `as String?` solution proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25664102/1187415 does not work anymore with Xcode 6.2 (tested in iOS 8 Simulator). Changing the property type to an optional (the "Old answer" in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25664102/1187415) still works.

Comment: This is also discussed in the developer forum: https://devforums.apple.com/message/995243#995243, https://devforums.apple.com/message/1110385#1110385 and the advice is to file a bug report.

Comment: `item.valueForKey("title") as String?` as proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27412036/1187415 works as well.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, @martin-r ! I tried `item.valueForKey("title") as String?` and that works for me. But nothing else did. If you'd like to propose that as an answer, I would be glad to tick it. Thanks!

Comment: The solution "as String?" doesn't work every time. For a NSDate non optional nil in CoreData works only if I logged it in printf before. It doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should make your title an optional if core data can return nil value for title

```
@NSManaged var title: String?
```

And test it without the cast

```
if let possibleTitle = historyItem.title{
    NSLog("possibleTitle was set OK")
} else {
    NSLog("possibleTitle was nil")
}
```

Comment: Agreed, Xcode's generated classes are dangerous in Swift, since Core Data can return nil even when the generated property is not optional.

Comment: Agree with Tom. It is advisable to update your generated Swift classes according to your "optional" settings in the data model.

Comment: I'd probably go farther and say that they should all be optional in Swift, because Core Data doesn't enforce rules about required attribute values until you save changes. There's still a window where the value could legitimately be nil.

Comment: Should we also check the "optional" checkbox into the datamodel file?

Comment: @Ben Only if it's supposed to be optional. I don't know if this is the best approach, but if the property isn't supposed to be optional, I give it the `!` ending in Swift so it's an error if nil, and I can still check if it's nil.